# How to get HTTP header value in AEM Sightly/HTL

Tags: aem, sling, sightly

I have this code:

```
<div data-sly-list.myitem="${request.getHeaderNames}" data-sly-unwrap>
  <pre>[${myitem}] [${request.getHeader[myitem]}]</pre>
</div>
```

Which produces a list of headers:

```
[Cookie] []
[Accept] []
[X-User-Agent-Type] []
[X-Request-ID] []
...
[X-Forwarded-For] []
[Accept-Language] []
```

Why does it get the header names, but not the values? I've tried

- quoted string names - `${request.getHeader['User-Agent']}`
- getHeader - `${request.getHeader[myitem]}`
- getHeaders - `${request.getHeaders[myitem]}`

How can I get the header value in the template?

(AEM 6.3)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no convenience for getting a specific header value directly from HTL, as you cannot invoke methods with parameters.

You could follow one of the following approaches:

1. Create your own helper use object that takes the request and wraps the headers in a `Map<String, List<Object>> getAllHeaders()`. Then you can grab it as: `${helper.allHeaders['Accept']}`
2. Create your own helper that grabs the request and extracts a certain header: `<sly data-sly-use.helper="${Helper @ header='Accept'}">${helper.headerValue}</sly>`

Comment: I always forget this. Thanks.